# Error capistrano deploying from a local folder

Tags: capistrano, deployment, local

I have a local repository for my app (created using TortoiseSVN) at c:\lap-svn\gws

My deploy.rb has:

```
set :user, '<removed>'
set :application, "gws"
set :repository,  "file:///c:/lap-svn/gws"
set :server, 'plantality.com'
set :applicationdir, 'gws'
set :use_sudo, false
set :keep_releases, 5
set :deploy_via, :copy

set :scm, :none
```

When I go to deploy I get an error:

```
C:\Ruby\GWS>cap deploy:cold
  * executing `deploy:cold'
  * executing `deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
  * executing `deploy:update_code'
  * getting (via checkout) revision  to C:/Users/Mike/AppData/Local/Temp/20100207162735
    executing locally: xcopy file:///c:/lap-svn/gws "C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Temp\20100207162735" \S\I\Y\Q\E
    Invalid number of parameters
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back 
  * executing "rm -rf /home/plantali/gws/releases/20100207162735; true"
    servers: ["plantality.com"]
Password:
    [plantality.com] executing command
    command finished
C:/TurboRDK/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.5.14/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy/strategy/copy.rb:94:in `initialize': No such file or directory - C:/Users/Mike/AppData/Local/Temp/20100207162735/REVISION (Errno::ENOENT)
```

which seems to have a problem with file called REVISION, but there's no such file in the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again I find my own answer twenty seconds after posting. Duh.

TortoiseSVN on it's own wasn't enough, I needed to install subversion and change the scm line in deploy.rb back to :subversion

Answer (score 1):

xcopy wasn't working with `set :deploy_via, :copy` because xcopy requires Windows-style paths.

```
set :repository,  "file:///c:/lap-svn/gws"
```

Because this repository path had forward slashes (/) in it, xcopy interpreted them as options, rather than as part of a path. Instead, try:

```
set :repository,  "C:\lap-svn\gws"
```

I realize that you already solved this problem a long time ago by working around it, but I wanted to post this for others' reference who run into this problem.